# Android - ListView inside Dialog

Tags: android, listview, dialog

Can anyone help me, how to add ListView inside dialog. I am trying adding ListView inside customDialog but getting errors.. ListView is not appearing.

Comment: What errors do you receive? Add relevant code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) to add a custom layout to a Dialog.

---

Your Fragment would need to extend the DialogFragment (the app.v4 one) class:

**BlankFragment.java**

```
public class BlankFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private ListView listView;

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.f_blank_list);

        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World", "Bye");
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter
                = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Then you can have anything inside your dialog setting it up as a layout:

**fragment_blank.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.BlankFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/f_blank_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, you would need to show it in a transaction from your MainActivity:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String BLANK_FRAGMENT_TAG = "FRAGMENT_TAG";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void loadFragment(View view) {
        BlankFragment blankFragment = new BlankFragment();
        blankFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), BLANK_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    }
}
```

---

This is the result:

[image: DialogFragment with list]

Answer (score 1):

You can find documentation for Dialogs here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

For a list in the dialog you can use:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_color)
       .setItems(R.array.colors_array, new 
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // The 'which' argument contains the index position
              // of the selected item
           }
    });
return builder.create();
}
```